# How does function wrapper initialization work in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

If I have this class

```
class TextBox : public Widget {
public:
    void addKeyPressHandler(std::function<void (std::string)>);
private:
    std::function<void (std::string)> keyPressHandler;
};
```

How do I know if the keyPressHandler has been set or not?  Can I initialize it to NULL and then test against that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with lambdas, which look like this: `[...](...){...}`. This is a *function wrapper*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) allows you to test whether it holds a callable target via its `operator bool()`.

For example:

```
if (keyPressHandler)
{
    keyPressHandler(someString);
}
else
    // TODO: Consider queuing events here if you don't want to miss keystrokes.
}
```

...will call the function only if it has a valid target. Meaning it has been assigned a function pointer, or anything else callable since it was initialized.

Comment: uhmm...what if I have many `std::functions` or many call for that, isn't it efficient if I initialize each of them with an empty lambda expression instead of check it over and over again?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `operator bool` member function

> 20.8.11.2.3 function capacity [func.wrap.func.cap]
>
> `explicit operator bool() const noexcept;`
>
> Returns: true if *this has a target, otherwise
>   false.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int
main ()
{
        std::function<void()> f;

        std::cout << (bool) f << std::endl;

        f = [](){};
        std::cout << (bool) f << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either test it in a boolean context (as the other answers state)

```
if (keyPressHandler)
    ...
```

or you can compare it against `nullptr`

```
if (keyPressHandler != nullptr)
    ...
```

Of course looking up the documentation for yourself would have been quicker than asking a question and waiting for an answer.  It's pretty obvious from the documentation Sean Cline linked to, which documents that `operator bool()` "checks if a valid target is contained"